# How to rename folders with name DD.MM.YYYY-X to YYMMDDIX on bash?

Tags: linux, bash, rename, file-rename

I have folders inside a directory with names having the pattern `DD.MM.YYYY-X` where `X` refers to an index from 0-9 to distinguish folders with names having the same date.

How could I use regex on bash to replace this pattern with `YYMMDDIX` where

- `I` is an actual `I` to signal that what follows is the index of the folder
- `YY` is the last two numbers in `YYYY`
- `DD` and `MM` are the same as in the original name

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this script in the same directory containing folders with names having the pattern `DD.MM.YYYY-X` will copy those folders in the same directory with naming syntax you requested.

#### `script2.sh` file containing the following

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*-*"  -type d -exec basename {} \;) ;do
  dd=$(cut -d'.' -f1 <<< "${dir}")
  mm=$(cut -d'.' -f2 <<< "${dir}")
  yyyy=$(cut -d'.' -f3 <<< "${dir}" | cut -d'-' -f1)
  yy="${yyyy: -2}"
  x="${dir: -1}"

  cp -rvi "${dir}" "${yy}${mm}${dd}I${x}"
done

exit 0
```

#### Script Output

```bash
'22.12.1983-1' -> '831222I1'
'22.12.1982-1' -> '821222I1'
'22.12.1983-0' -> '831222I0'
'22.12.1982-2' -> '821222I2'
```

#### `ls` output after running script

```bash
22.12.1982-1  22.12.1982-2  22.12.1983-0  22.12.1983-1  821222I1  821222I2  831222I0  831222I1 script2.sh
```

### Recommendation (Update #1)

It is recommended to update and use unique variable names. Like with a `_` prefix.

Here `dd=` variable can be changed to `_dd=...` to avoid conflicting/confusing with the `dd` command.